# Hide a page section then reveal it when a link is clicked- JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question within a page and I want the user to be able to be able to have a go answering before the answer is revealed. So they have two options. one link to show some clues and ideas and one link to show the completed conclusion. firstly I tried setting the original property to not display the section then using .show() to reveal it but that wasn't working. Then I had some already working code with a similar purpose so tried using the .addClass method instead. That didn't work either so I assume it must be my links or something I just can't see because I am new to JQuery. Any advice would be much appreciated! Here's my code:

```
    <section id="page6section2"><div class="page-header"><h1>Some Ideas</h1></div>
    <section id="page6section3"><div class="page-header"><h1>Conclusion</h1></div>

    <p><a href="#page6section2" id="someideas">Click here for some clues and ideas!</a>
    </p>
    <p><a href="#page6section3" id="conclusion">Click here for the conclusion!</a>
```

```
    .hidesection2 {display: none;}
    .hidesection3 {display: none;}  



    $(function() {
    $('#page6section2').addClass('hidesection2');});
    jQuery('#someideas').click(function(){
    jQuery('#page6section2').removeClass('hidesection2'); });
    $(function() {
    $('#page6section3').addClass('hidesection3');});
    jQuery('#conclusion').click(function(){
    jQuery('#page6section3').removeClass('hidesection3'); });
```

I'm sure there is probably an easier and more condensed way to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

put your function to window load:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
   $('#page6section2').addClass('hidesection2');
   jQuery('#someideas').click(function(){
       jQuery('#page6section2').removeClass('hidesection2'); 
   });

   $('#page6section3').addClass('hidesection3');
   jQuery('#conclusion').click(function(){
        jQuery('#page6section3').removeClass('hidesection3'); 
   });
});
```

your links DOM might not yet been loaded when the script was executed. Thats why you should put it to windows.load

Comment: I updated my answer, there are some syntax error with my previous answer, btw you get the point, right?  put your function to windows.load:D

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. Yeah I understand, I just thought that it was default after the page loads if my script is at the bottom of the page? anyway, I tried that fix but the sections were still visible from the start. when I changed the CSS so they initially had visibility set to hidden and just tried to addClass method which had the visibility set to visible without bothering to add the class and make them not displayed first it wouldn't work again and they just stayed hidden. I don't know why that code doesn't seem to have any affect when the rest of my code does?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using the data attribute, a CSS class and the toggleClass() method :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-section').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
      $target = $('section[data-id="' + id + '"]');
    $target.toggleClass('shown');
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}
.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="show-section" data-id="1">Section 1</p>
<p class="show-section" data-id="2">Section 2</p>

<section data-id="1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum possimus, facere consequuntur alias, nesciunt vitae vero aliquid quo repellat totam sed. Aspernatur assumenda, dignissimos molestias iste temporibus dolores repellendus.</p>
</section>

<section data-id="2">
  <h1>section 2</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore eum possimus, facere consequuntur alias, nesciunt vitae vero aliquid quo repellat totam sed. Aspernatur assumenda, dignissimos molestias iste temporibus dolores repellendus.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, I know your code is perfect because I can see it work but when i copy it directly into the content management system I am using it doesn't work so it must be a problem with the system rather than with the code. Thanks for your help getting me that far because I can't trust my own code for troubleshooting and always just assume there's errors in it. At least now i know it's something else and will inquire directly to the developer for help. Thanks for your time anyway though Mehdi

Comment: Well, it's difficult to adapt to your environment without knowing exactly what you can do.